# For some reason. IF statement is working....Ive tried If/else with no luck either

Tags: php, if-statement, session, session-cookies, session-variables

Only the 'Admin' if statement runs correctly. Anything else will jump to the un-nested else...any reason as to why?

Note: Yes, I've checked the spelling of the ranks...they are spelled correctly

Will redirect after user has succesfully logged in
(login-sucessful.php):

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    if ($_SESSION["rank"] == 'Admin'){//Check if Admin
      header("location:/panel/admin/profile.php");
    } elseif ($_SESSION["rank"] == 'Faculty'){//Check if Faculty
      header("location:/panel/student/profile.php");
    } elseif ($_SESSION["rank"] == 'Student'){//Check if Student
      header("location:/panel/faculty/profile.php");
    }
  }else{
    header("location:log-in.php");
  }
 ?>
```

login page (login.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
$host = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password!";
$database = "database";
$message = "";
try
{
     $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$database", $username, $password);
     $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     if(isset($_POST["login"]))
     {
          if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
          {
               $message = '<label class="red-text text-darken-2">All fields are required</label>';
          }
          else
          {
               $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = :username AND password = :password";
               $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
               $statement->execute(
                    array(
                         'username'     =>     $_POST["username"],
                         'password'     =>     $_POST["password"]
                    )
               );
               $count = $statement->rowCount();
               if($count > 0)
               {
                    $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
                    $_SESSION["rank"] = $statement->fetchColumn(3);
                    header("location:login_success.php");

               }
               else
               {
                    $message = '<label class="red-text text-darken-2">Wrong Email or Password</label>';
               }
          }
     }
}
catch(PDOException $error)
{
     $message = $error->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Login Table:
[Login Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvysp.png)

Comment: No repro ~ https://3v4l.org/qP4Tm

Comment: Can you show the login table? want to see what is in column 3

Comment: A good practice is to place an exit after an `header('Location:...` in order to prevent further code execution

Comment: Login Table provided

Comment: can you print $_SESSION["rank"] and check every time you are getting the proper rank name?

Comment: Wow....Cant believe I just spent an hour on this....its 2am and im exhausted...must be the reason this slipped up....
```} elseif ($_SESSION["rank"] == 'Faculty'){//Check if Faculty
      header("location:/panel/student/profile.php");
    } elseif ($_SESSION["rank"] == 'Student'){//Check if Student
      header("location:/panel/faculty/profile.php");
``` files linked to wrong directory which forced it to shoot back to login page (cause rank wasnt allowed) Thanks so much guys...I feel like a dumbass...Going to sleep now

Comment: Sorry, if that info amounts to a solution you HAVE to put it into an answer instead of into the question. Feel free to edit the question for putting in info that you realised in hindsight were needed to find the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wow....Cant believe I just spent an hour on this....its 2am and im exhausted...must be the reason this slipped up.... } elseif ($_SESSION["rank"] == 'Faculty'){//Check if Faculty       header("location:/panel/student/profile.php");     } elseif ($_SESSION["rank"] == 'Student'){//Check if Student       header("location:/panel/faculty/profile.php");  files linked to wrong directory which forced it to shoot back to login page (cause rank wasnt allowed) Thanks so much guys...I feel like a dumbass...Going to sleep now

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exact reason (will need more code for that) But try doing this

```
    if (empty($_SESSION['username']) && empty($_SESSION['rank'])){
        header("location:log-in.php");
    }
    else if ($_SESSION["rank"] == 'Admin'){//Check if Admin
      header("location:/panel/admin/profile.php");
    } else if ($_SESSION["rank"] == 'Faculty'){//Check if Faculty
      header("location:/panel/faculty/profile.php");
    } else if ($_SESSION["rank"] == 'Student'){//Check if Student
      header("location:/panel/student/profile.php");
    }
```

Comment: Nope...No luck :(

Thats just my login-success.php file....
Ive updated the post with the initial login php

Comment: your condition seems to be working for me and even for @Phil in above comment. Can you check if rank is properly assigned or not in case.

Comment: Rank is properly assigned in login php file.
$_SESSION["rank"] = $statement->fetchColumn(3);

Comment: Found solution....code was shooting to the wrong directory...Sorry about that man...Thanks for the help...Very much appreicated

Comment: Happens lots of times...